# Old questions should have a visual age indicator

Tags: feature-request

Occasionally, a very old question (for example, [Error In a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134329/error-in-a-for-loop)) gets bumped to the top of the Top Questions queue, usually from some minor editing.

I spend a couple minutes reading the question, comments, and answer before I realize that this question is over 3 years old.

I would like to request that old questions that get bumped display a highlighted banner indicating their age and what caused the bump. This will allow me to more easily evaluate if I should pay attention to it.

[image]

Comment: Downvote, close, and delete that question with extreme prejudice. It's both unclear and too broad.

Comment: There are ways for things to get bumped *so* that you will look at them. This is [by-design] and shouldn't be defeated.

Comment: @Cupcake I agree with you, it's surprising that this question was not downvoted or closed. But this is not the point of the askers question, and you should not down vote this question (not the example) because of the example he used.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ***never ever assume that someone who comments on a question is also someone who voted on it***. For instance, I have not voted on this Meta question, one way or the other.

Comment: @Cupcake **Never ever assume that "you should not" implies that "you did"**. I told you that you should not, not that you have already done so.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek `:P`

Comment: [Duplicate.  DAMN YOU META SPLIT!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions)

Comment: @Will Thanks for posting that. The author of that question makes a better argument than I did for displaying the age of old questions, but I like my mockup better. :)

Comment: @AaronBrager: The author just told me that he likes his mock-up better.  Then he wiped my bottom, fed me lunch, and decided he was taking me out tonight.

Comment: I agree that old questions (as long as they are asked well) have great relevance and should be preserved. I also don't agree that there should be some large, cumbersome banner pointing out a questions age. However, to just put something under the title saying this question was asked x yrs/mnths ago and was last commented on x yrs/mnths ago is a good idea. Although the question is well written technologies change. Someone could ask about putting blocks together on a webpage and have the answer to 'float' them whereas now it might be more appropriate to flexbox them or inline-block them etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No!

Questions on Stack Overflow aren't supposed to age away into obscurity, with people ignoring them because they are old.

If that were the case, why marr them with some kind of indicator? Why not just delete them outright and save everyone even the 3 seconds they'd consume processing the visual indicator?

Because there's nothing wrong with old questions! There's no reason to ignore them. You can browse them, read them, learn from them, edit them, improve them, *answer them*, and a whole host of other things, all without holding your nose. In fact, our model *encourages* you to do so.

It is very confusing and concerning to me that you appear to have sentiments that differ from this.

> I spend a couple minutes reading the question, comments, and answer before I realize that this question is over 3 years old.

So what? If it is a good question that was well-answered, then this was not time wasted. If it had not been well-answered, then that's a prime opportunity for you—post an answer! Of course, if it's a *bad* question, then I guess it does kind of waste your time. But that's not unique to its being old. It would be just as much a waste of time if it were brand new. We have a way of dispatching such questions: we downvote them, close them, and ultimately delete them. All questions are eligible for and should receive this treatment when appropriate, *regardless* of their age.

In this case, I'll grant that you did come across a bad question. It looks like it did waste your time (and now you've wasted all our time by forcing us to look at it :-p), and I'm sorry to hear that. But when you come across stuff like this, you need to help us by taking action against it. Since you've brought it to the attention of Meta users, it's been downvoted and closed. You could have spurred this process along yourself when you came across it by simply voting to close it yourself.

Now, just so that I'm not misunderstood, I'll say it again: it would be very nice if we could find a way to prevent bad questions from getting posted that we have to waste our time reading and dispatching. But that has *nothing to do with age*, and everything to do with quality. There tons of high-quality questions with excellent answers that are over 3 years old. I know, because every time I write code, it seems like I have Stack Overflow open on one of my screens, reading awesome answers that help me to arrive at solutions to problems I'm experiencing. I don't look at the date, I look at the content.

> I would like to request that old questions that get bumped display a highlighted banner indicating their age and what caused the bump. This will allow me to more easily evaluate if I should pay attention to it.

Bumps can only be caused by a few things:

1. Initial posting.
2. Editing.
3. The posting of a new answer.
4. The post being reopened.

All of those three things are "interesting" activity, and we *want* other users to notice that they've occurred. That is the only way you can determine whether that activity was legitimate or not, and that is key to our community moderation model. If you see a poor quality question get posted, you have the tools to help dispose of it. If you see a bad answer posted, you should downvote it and potentially flag it for disposal. If you see a bad edit get made, you have the tools to roll it back and undo the harm.

If you only want to see "new" questions, we have a place you can do that. Click the "Questions" tab, and then sort by "newest". In other words, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). You won't see anything that's been bumped for any reason but #1: a brand new question being posted for the first time.

---

**Bonus Chatter:** The only case in which I would support this is for really old questions that no longer meet our guidelines. The ones we have since closed, but haven't deleted because they contain valuable information that might still be of use to people. We had a big debate a few years ago about what to do with these questions. You can find it if you care by searching on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (the Meta site we used before this one unique to Stack Overflow was created).

Some people wanted to just delete them outright (and many, indeed, were deleted), others wanted to leave the information accessible. But we all pretty much agreed that the questions needed to be closed and that we didn't want people looking at them and getting the wrong impression about what types of questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.

A compromise was reached, where we lock these questions for posterity. The content is all still available, but they cannot be interacted with. This is called a historical lock. The current implementation hides the voting arrows and puts a gray banner on the page (similar to the "closed" banner), but doesn't otherwise make it particularly obvious that there is something special about the question.

There were proposals then (I think one of them was mine, but certainly Will had an idea similar to this) to make these questions visually distinct in an impossible-to-miss way. I think that's a perfectly valid suggestion, but it would *only* apply to historically locked questions that are basically dancing on the edge of the deletion cliff. It is not appropriate for normal questions just because they're old.

Comment: This. What's the point in appearing in a search engine if you don't give a crap about old questions.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I have with the above answer is that some correct answers become incorrect over time as technology changes. Especially in web development. Old workarounds can become antipatterns over time with new versions and new frameworks.

It's frustrating to be looking for an answer to a question and realize the answer you have been trying to understand is 5-10 years old. Then you have to scan through the UI looking at the tiny date text. And maybe the page as a whole is full of great answers and looks like a well researched and thought out question/answers page--but then you realize that the **all** the answers are old enough that you can't be sure if they are still relevant. And you don't know cause you came here for help.

It's totally doable to look through the tiny dates, but it would be nice to have something clearer and easier. Maybe the ability to sort answers by date descending, not just ascending, maybe with the ability to make that a permanent user setting. Idk.

Or better yet, some way to help make clear that old answers may need updating. I think part of the problem is that these used to be, and have the appearance of, a good question and great answers. They don't look on the surface to need any new answers, but they do. Closing something as a duplicate can draw attention to an old question/answers, but what if when I'm looking I find an old answered question first and never post a duplicate (as is desired)?

Is there anything in the system that helps a page of answers to evolve appropriately over time?

Comment: I did find the link above to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/automatic-visual-indication-of-old-questions . I don't think something blatant in the UI would be helpful, but it would be good if there was a way to encourage answer evolution. Maybe there is and I don't know about it.